# open new window, run a $scope function in that window, a better way

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So, I have two single page applications, these two apps both contain a list of items, in `Application A` we have `List A`, and in `Application B` we have `List B`.

an item in `List A` can be the parent for items in `List B`, one to many relations.

If a user clicks an item in `App A`, he gets the option to `view related items`, this will open up `App B` in a separate window (new tab), and filter `List B` to only show related items to the clicked item in `App A`.

This means I have to open a new window, and run a function when that window is ready, and pass the `ID` of the clicked item in order to filter my list.

```
$scope.openNewWindow = function(id){

    var popup = window.open('newPageUrl');

      // check to see when opened page is ready
    var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function() {
        if (popup.document.readyState === "complete") {
            clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);
            // function on App B
            popup.functionToRunWhenReady(id);
        }
    }, 50);
};
```

The function, `functionToRunWhenReady()` is a javascript function, and has to run the actual function to filter my list, which is a `$scope` function, the reason is that I can't access the `$scope` function from my other application

```
function functionToRunWhenReady(id) {
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {

        var scope = angular.element($('#myAppDiv')).scope();

        scope.$apply(function() {
             // scope function to filter the list
            scope.setFilter(id);
        });
    });
}
```

As you can see here I check if `document` is ready, access the `scope` by doing `var scope = angular.element($('#myAppDiv')).scope();` and then run my `setFilter(id)` function

This works, but I can't believe that this is the best way to go about this.

**tl;dr** How do I open a new window, then run a $scope function on the new application, in a way that is not bad practice?

**Edit:** I see people are suggesting `$routeparams`, but I don't really know how that works, or if it works in my apps (they are both *single page apps*), so further explanation of that would be great

Comment: Can't you club those two pages into a single angular application?

Comment: @Chinni that was my first approach, but the second app is widely used, and only in some instances is an item related to the list in the first app

Answer (score 3):

Send ID as a GET parameter to Application B. You can then access it directly in controller without any delays using $routeParams.

Answer (score 2):

In Application A, you don't need any special code to open a window. Just a `target="blank"` link in your markup.

```
<a href="http://applicationB_url/{{itemA.id}}/items" target="blank">{{itemA.name}}</a>
```

And then in Application B, depending on your router, use `$stateParams` (for `ui router`) or `$routeParams` to access the id in your controller.

If you want to run a function on startup, just check for the existence of the id in your Application B controller. Something like:

```
if($stateParams.id) {
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend changing the redirect to be the following
`var popup = window.open('newPageUrl?id=' + id);`

and then on the second webpage, just parse the id out of the url:

```
var search = document.location.href;
var id = JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(search).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}')['id'];
```

A better alternative would be to store the data as a cookie
`cookiesave('id', id);`
and then
`var id = cookieget('id');`